# Python завершение процесса в Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, bat, процесс

Есть процесс запущенный через bat файл. При определенных обстоятельствах мне требуется его полностью закрыть, как если бы я нашел этот процесс в Диспетчере задач и нажал на нём Завершить задачу.
Пробовал с помощью пакета psutil, вызывать методы kill() и terminate(), а так же пробовал через os.system(f"taskkill /Pid {proc.pid} /f /t"). Результат один и тот же во всех 3х случаях, консоль не закрывается полностью, консоль остается открытой и ждет нажатия любой клавиши.
Может есть способ закрыть задачу сразу или послать доп команду на завершение?

Comment: Разобрался! Сначала сохранил pid процесса в переменную, а затем уже вызвал функцию os.system(f"taskkill /Pid {pid}"). В таком случае консоль сразу закрывается. А если получать pid в вызове функции os.system(f"taskkill /Pid {proc.pid} /f /t"), то консоль ждет нажатия кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Однажды мне понадобилось похожее и я решил вот так:

```
# удаляет процессы архиваторов в памяти
def kill_proc_archivers():
    process_winrar = ['winrar.exe', 'winzip.exe', '7z.exe']
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if process.name().lower() in process_winrar:
            process.kill()
```

Comment: Я пробовал этот метод, он тоже не закрывает консоль. Процесс выполнения программы останавливается, а консоль так же ждёт подтверждения ввода.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда так - файл bat запускает процесс через start, а уже само приложение закрывается через питон.
start в начале строки запускает приложение закрывая командную строку.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже разобрался. Оказалось что не все процессы закрывал. Там при запуске бат файла запускаются 4 процесса, основные из них 2 и плюс ко всему по не знанию использовал proc.ppid(), вместо proc.pid и по этому не то что нужно закрывалось.